# Formatting a number by passing number of decimal places as a parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, formatting, decimal, rounding

(In Scala) I've been trying to create a function that converts a *Double* to a certain number of decimal points. If I wanted it to return a *String* to 2 decimal places I would do this:

```
    def roundBy2(num: Double): String = f"$num%1.2f"
```

But if I wanted to pass the number of decimal places through a parameter my first attempt might be:

```
    def roundBy(num: Double)(dp: Int): String = f"$num%1.${dp}f"
```

But this throws up:

> Missing conversion operator in '%1'; use %% for literal %, %n for
>   newline   def roundBy(num: Double)(dp: Int): String =
>   f"$num%1.${dp}f"

I know that when using *interpolators* I don't have to use curly braces when referencing a value inside the quotations but of course that would just leave `f"$num%1.$dpf"` and I would be mistaken for trying to use a value that hasn't been declared, i.e. `$dpf`

I feel sure that this is attainable in this way but I am lacking the syntax so I'm hoping that there is an easy fix. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use `.format(num)` instead:

```scala
def roundBy(num: Double)(dp: Int): String = s"%1.${dp}f".format(num)
```

Comment: Thanks - that will do it Federico. So simple when you know!